# pythonic way to identify names in url and match it with an existing set of names

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, parsing

Hello this is a problem I want to resolve but I am stuck.

Given a list of urls I want to do the following :

1. extract the name within the url
2. match the name found from the url to a dictionary of existing names
3. have 1 dictionary of all the names found, an split the found names into 2 separate dictionaries, 1 associated to the names found in the dictionary and another associated to no names found

example:

```
INPUT : 
urls = ['www.twitter.com/users/aoba-joshi/$#fsd=43r', 
        'www.twitter.com/users/chrisbrown-e2/#4f=34ds', 
        'www.facebook.com/celebrity/neil-degrasse-tyson',
        'www.instagram.com/actor-nelson-bigetti']

# the key is the ID associated to the names, and the values are all the potential names

existing_names = {1 : ['chris brown', 'chrisbrown', 'Brown Chris', 'brownchris'] ,
                  2 : ['nelson bigetti', 'bigetti nelson', 'nelsonbigetti', 'bigettinelson'],
                  3 : ['neil degrasse tyson', 'tyson neil degreasse', 'tysonneildegrasse', 'neildegrassetyson']}


OUTPUT : 
# names_found will be a dictionary with the key as the URL and the values as the found name
names_found = {'www.twitter.com/users/aoba-joshi/$#fsd=43r' : 'aoba joshi',
               'www.twitter.com/users/chrisbrown-e2/#4f=34ds' : 'chris brown',
               'www.facebook.com/celebrity/neil-degrasse-tyson' : 'neil degrasse tyson',
               'www.instagram.com/actor-nelson-bigetti' : 'nelson bigetti'}

# existing_names_found is a dictionary where the keys are the found name, and the values are the corresponding list of names in the existing names dictionary

existing_names_found = {'chris brown' : ['chris brown', 'chrisbrown', 'Brown Chris', 'brownchris'],
                        'neil degrasse tyson' : ['neil degrasse tyson', 'tyson neil degreasse', 'tysonneildegrasse', 'neildegrassetyson'],
                        'nelson bigetti' : ['nelson bigetti', 'bigetti nelson', 'nelsonbigetti', 'bigettinelson']}

# new_names_found is a dictionary with the keys as the new name found, and the values as the url associated to the new found name
new_names_found = {'aoba joshi' : 'www.twitter.com/users/aoba-joshi/$#fsd=43r'}
```

Comment: Good you have added input & expected output, but forgot to add the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well ... if i got correctly what u want to do ... here is something what should work

```
for link in links_list:
    link_split = link.split('/')
    name_list = link_split[2].split('-')     # makes from chris-brown-xx => chrisbrownxx
    name = ""
    for part in name:
        name + part
    for (key, value) in existing_names:    # check if the name is in the list
        for name_x in value:
            name_x = # same as I did with name_list, but this time with " "
            if name_x in name.lower():
                # append it to new_names_found
```

(Sorry in advance, I am typing this on my phone, but hopefully it will be helpful :))

(alternatively, you can try to look if it contains both parts of a text ... but that would fail on something like this -> "Luke Luk" and checking it on "Luke O'Niel") ... There is alot of proble

Answer (score 1):

Do get you started, here are the steps to make this program:

1. Create a `for` to look through each individual url and using the `split('/')` function break every url into a list and search for the 2 value in that list.
2. Then you can use another `for` loop to go through the keys and values of the `existing_names` dictionary. Within that loop include an `if` statement that compares the name you extracted to the names present.
3. Then you add those values to the dictionaries or lists you want.

Answer (score 1):

for the first part in identifying name in the url you can do something like :

```
urls = [i for i in urls if 'name' in i]

found_celeb = {}
for url in urls:
    link_split = url.split('=')[-1].split(',')[-1]
    celeb_name = ' '.join(link_split)
    found_celeb[url] = celeb_name
```